# ¿Como ocultar el menu al darle clic en sus items con Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un **menu** que se despliega ocupando el 100% en pantallas chicas, cada **item** del menu tiene un **[routerLink]** que funciona perfecto, el problema es que al hacer click en los **items**, la **view** se muestra pero el **menu** sigue ocupando el 100% de la pantalla, y yo quiero que desaparezca o se oculte cuando se carga la **view**.

Al desplegar el menu:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer clic en algun item (como pueden ver la view del login se muestra)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el codigo:**

```html
<nav id="menu" class="menu">
      <a [routerLink]="'/home'"><i class="fa fa-home mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
      <a [routerLink]="'/contact/contact'"><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contacto</a>
      <a [routerLink]="'auth/login'"><i class="fa fa-user mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a>
</nav>
```

```css
.menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(41, 50, 64, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

// clase del boton que despliega el menu
#menu-bar:checked ~ .menu{
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

lo que intente hacer fue: vincularle a cada item una **funcion hideMenu()**, con esta funcion
intento desde **typescript** ocultar al **menu** agregandole una **clase "hideMenu"** y los correspondientes **router.navigate** dependiendo del item clickeado. Los **router.navigate** funcionan, pero el menu no se oculta.

```html
<nav id="menu" class="menu">
    <a (click)="hideMenu('home')"><i class="fa fa-home mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
    <a (click)="hideMenu('contact')"><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contacto</a>
    <a (click)="hideMenu('login')"><i class="fa fa-user mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a>
</nav>
```

**desde typescript**

```js
 hideMenu(name:string){
    console.log(name);
    const element = document.getElementById("menu");
    element.classList.add("hideMenu");
    
    if(name === 'home'){
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
    
    if(name === 'contact'){
      this.router.navigate(['/contact']);
    }

    if(name === 'login'){
      this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
    }
}
```

**Aca la clase hideMenu**

```css
.hideMenu{
  .menu{
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de esta forma:

En el **nav/menu** utilizo **[NgClass]** donde le agrego **2 clases**, una clase para **ocultar el menu** y la otra para **mostrarlo**.
A cada **item** del menu incluyendo el **boton toogle** le incluyo la funcion **hideMenu()** en el evento **(click)**.

**component.html**

```html
 <!-- toogle -->
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar" (click)="hideMenu('menu-bar')"/>
<label class="icon-menu" for="menu-bar">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</label>

<nav id="menu" class="menu" [ngClass]="{'hideMenu': hide, 'showMenu': show && !hide}>
    <a (click)="hideMenu('home')"><i class="fa fa-home mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
    <a (click)="hideMenu('contact')"><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contacto</a>
    <a (click)="hideMenu('login')"><i class="fa fa-user mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a>
</nav>
```

**component.sass/css**

```css
.hideMenu{
  transform: translateX(-100%) !important;
}

.showMenu{
  transform: translateX(0%) !important;
}
```

En **typescript** **component.ts**

```js
// variables que dependiendo su estado activaran las clases en el menu del component.html
hide: boolean = false;
show: boolean = false;

hideMenu(name: string) {
    switch (name) {
      // cuando es click en el toogle
      case 'menu-bar':
        if (this.show === false) {
          // se muestra el menu
          this.hide = false;
          this.show = true;
        } else {
          // se oculta el menu
          this.hide = true;
          this.show = false;
        }
        break;
      // cuando hay click en item del menu
      case 'home':
        this.hide = true;
        this.show = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        break;
      case 'contact':
        this.hide = true;
        this.show = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/contact/contact']);
        break;
      case 'login':
        this.hide = true;
        this.show = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
        break;
      case 'carrito':
        this.hide = true;
        this.show = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/purchase/form-purchase']);
        break;
      default:
      // code block
    }
  }
```

Comment: porque no usas switch?

Comment: Ahi lo cambie con switch.